# Resolve input is not bound when routing to downgraded component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I just upgraded to ui-router v1 to use the `.component:` state property, but the `resolve` data doesn't get bound to my `@Input()` property.

The component is downgraded from an Angular component with `downgradeComponent` from `@angular/upgrade/static`.

```
.directive('itemCreate', downgradeComponent({
  component: ItemCreateComponent,
  inputs: ['user'],
}))
```

router code:

```
.state('item.create', {
  url: '/create',
  component: 'itemCreate',
  resolve: {
    user: () => ({name: 'david'}),
  },
}
```

the component is instantiated but `user` is undefined.

This **does** work

```
.state('item.create', {
  url: '/create',
  template: '<item-create [user]="$resolve.user"></item-create>',
  resolve: {
    user: () => ({ name: 'david' }),
  },
})
```

Comment: have you found any solution for this?